# Добавление своего виджета в QMdiArea и растягивание окна

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qmdiarea

Есть свой виджет (`Forma()`), в ней пару кнопочек в `layout`e`.

Добавляю:

```
        sub = QMdiSubWindow()
        sub.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        sub.setWidget(Forma())
        self.mdi.addSubWindow(sub)
        sub.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Работает, но при растягивание окна мой виджет остается на месте. 
Но, в след. примере:

```
    sub = QMdiSubWindow()
    sub.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
    sub.setWidget(QPushButton('Show'))
    self.mdi.addSubWindow(sub)
    sub.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я получаю требуемый результат (при растягивание окна, кнопка расширяется). 
Как сделать такое с моим виджетом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Работает абсолютно одинаково. Вот пример:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Forma(QWidget):                                               # Есть свой виджет(Forma())
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button1 = QPushButton('Forma: Show button1...', self)   # в ней пару кнопочек в layout`e
        self.button2 = QPushButton('Forma: Show button2...', self)   # в ней пару кнопочек в layout`e
        self.grid = QGridLayout(self)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.button1, 0, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.button2, 1, 0)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    count = 0
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.mdi = QMdiArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mdi)
        bar  = self.menuBar()
        file = bar.addMenu("File")
        file.addAction("New")
        file.addAction("cascade")
        file.addAction("Tiled")
        file.triggered[QAction].connect(self.windowaction)
        self.setWindowTitle("MDI demo")

        sub = QMdiSubWindow()
        sub.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        sub.setWidget(QPushButton('Show'))
        sub.setWindowTitle("PushButton "+str(MainWindow.count))
        self.mdi.addSubWindow(sub)
        sub.show()        


    def windowaction(self, q):
        print("triggered-> q ->", q.text())
        if q.text() == "New":
            MainWindow.count = MainWindow.count+1
            sub = QMdiSubWindow()
            sub.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
            sub.setWidget(Forma())                                    # <-------
            sub.setWindowTitle("subwindow"+str(MainWindow.count))
            self.mdi.addSubWindow(sub)
            sub.show()

        if q.text() == "cascade":
            self.mdi.cascadeSubWindows()

        if q.text() == "Tiled":
            self.mdi.tileSubWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]